# Type-pun uint64_t as two uint32_t in C++20

Tags: c++, c++20, type-punning

This code to read a `uint64_t` as two `uint32_t` is UB due to the strict aliasing rule:

```
uint64_t v;
uint32_t lower = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(&v)[0];
uint32_t upper = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(&v)[1];
```

Likewise, this code to write the upper and lower part of an `uint64_t` is UB due to the same reason:

```
uint64_t v;
uint32_t* lower = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(&v);
uint32_t* upper = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(&v) + 1;

*lower = 1;
*upper = 1;
```

How can one write this code in a safe and clean way in modern C++20, potentially using `std::bit_cast`?

Comment: How do you want to handle endianess?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using [std::bit_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast):

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/Yjboc5esa)

```
#include <bit>
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    uint64_t x = 0x12345678'87654321ULL;
    // Convert one u64 -> two u32
    auto v = std::bit_cast<std::array<uint32_t, 2>>(x);
    std::cout << std::hex << v[0] << " " << v[1] << std::endl;
    // Convert two u32 -> one u64
    auto y = std::bit_cast<uint64_t>(v);
    std::cout << std::hex << y << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
87654321 12345678
1234567887654321
```

---

[std::bit_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast) is available only in C++20. Prior to C++20 you can manually implement `std::bit_cast` through [std::memcpy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy), with one exception that such implementation is not `constexpr` like C++20 variant:

```
template <class To, class From>
inline To bit_cast(From const & src) noexcept {
    //return std::bit_cast<To>(src);
    static_assert(std::is_trivially_constructible_v<To>,
        "Destination type should be trivially constructible");
    To dst;
    std::memcpy(&dst, &src, sizeof(To));
    return dst;
}
```

---

For this specific case of integers quite optimal would be just to do bit shift/or arithmetics to convert one u64 to two u32 and back again. `std::bit_cast` is more generic, supporting any trivially constructible type, although std::bit_cast solution should be same optimal as bit arithmetics on modern compilers with high level of optimization.

One extra profit of bit arithmetics is that it handles correctly endianess, it is endianess independent, unlike `std::bit_cast`.

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/zsefoxzM8)

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    uint64_t x = 0x12345678'87654321ULL;
    // Convert one u64 -> two u32
    uint32_t lo = uint32_t(x), hi = uint32_t(x >> 32);
    std::cout << std::hex << lo << " " << hi << std::endl;
    // Convert two u32 -> one u64
    uint64_t y = (uint64_t(hi) << 32) | lo;
    std::cout << std::hex << y << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
87654321 12345678
123456788765432
```

**Notice!** As @Jarod42 [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69911406/type-pun-uint64-t-as-two-uint32-t-in-c20/69911528#comment123585973_69911528), solution with bit shifting is not equivalent to `memcpy`/`bit_cast` solution, their equivalence depends on endianess. On little endian CPU `memcpy`/`bit_cast` gives least significant half (lo) as array element `v[0]` and most significant (hi) in `v[1]`, while on big endian least significant (lo) goes to `v[1]` and most significant goes to `v[0]`. While bit-shifting solution is endianess independent, and on all systems gives most significant half (hi) as `uint32_t(num_64 >> 32)` and least significant half (lo) as `uint32_t(num_64)`.

Comment: You can manually implement `std::bit_cast`, but note that C++20 `std::bit_cast` is `constexpr` which isn't possible without some compiler magic.

Comment: Possibly OT: For some reason, GCC added a single-instruction overhead with `bit_cast`: https://godbolt.org/z/seoM4za9d (Clang did not).

Comment: @DanielLangr I think this overhead only happens if you do this inside separate function. When you inline this function or use its code as a part of bigger code then compiler should better optimize away extra instructions. But to me looks weird that compiler decided to use extra `RAX` in third function without using `RDI` directly as in first two functions.

Comment: @DanielLangr If you don't use references for return values, everything is optimized into basically nothingness: https://godbolt.org/z/dMfxdah6G

Comment: Notice that the solution with manual bitshift is not equivalent to `memcpy`/`bitcast` with endianess.

Comment: @Jarod42 As you suggested, just now added a **Notice!** to my post explaining endianess difference between `bitcast` and `bit-shifting` solutions.

Comment: To match the arithmatic (seemingly the goal), use `std::endian` to decide the order

Answer (score 2):

> in a safe and clean way

Do not use reinterpret_cast. Do not depend on unclear code that depends on some specific compiler settings and fishy, uncertain behavior. Use exact arithmetic operations with well-known defined result. Classes and operator overloads are all there waiting for you. For example, some global functions:

```
#include <iostream>

struct UpperUint64Ref {
   uint64_t &v;
   UpperUint64Ref(uint64_t &v) : v(v) {}
   UpperUint64Ref operator=(uint32_t a) {
      v &= 0x00000000ffffffffull;
      v |= (uint64_t)a << 32;
      return *this;
   }
   operator uint64_t() {
      return v;
   }
};
struct LowerUint64Ref { 
    uint64_t &v;
    LowerUint64Ref(uint64_t &v) : v(v) {}
    /* as above */
};
UpperUint64Ref upper(uint64_t& v) { return v; }
LowerUint64Ref lower(uint64_t& v) { return v; }

int main() {
   uint64_t v;
   upper(v) = 1;
}
```

Or interface object:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Uint64Ref {
   uint64_t &v;
   Uint64Ref(uint64_t &v) : v(v) {}
   struct UpperReference {
       uint64_t &v;
       UpperReference(uint64_t &v) : v(v) {}
       UpperReference operator=(uint32_t a) {
           v &= 0x00000000ffffffffull;
           v |= (uint64_t)a << 32u;
       }
   };
   UpperReference upper() {
      return v;
   }
   struct LowerReference {
       uint64_t &v;
       LowerReference(uint64_t &v) : v(v) {}
   };
   LowerReference lower() { return v; }
};
int main() {
   uint64_t v;
   Uint64Ref r{v};
   r.upper() = 1;
}
```

Comment: Notice that this answer would be independent of endianess, contrary to `memcpy`/`bitcast` usage. Not sure what is expected though.

Comment: Great answer. https://commandcenter.blogspot.com/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html?m=1 should be required reading for everyone.

Comment: This would have been the best you could do before C++20. Now bit_cast (with std::endian) is as fast or faster and is defined behavior

Answer (score 1):

Using `std::memcpy`

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstring>

void foo(uint64_t& v, uint32_t low_val, uint32_t high_val) {
    std::memcpy(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&v), &low_val,
                sizeof(low_val));
    std::memcpy(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&v) + sizeof(low_val),
                &high_val, sizeof(high_val));
}

int main() {
    uint64_t v = 0;
    foo(v, 1, 2);
}
```

With `O1`, the compiler reduces `foo` to:

```
        mov     DWORD PTR [rdi], esi
        mov     DWORD PTR [rdi+4], edx
        ret
```

Meaning there are no extra copies made, `std::memcpy` just serves as a hint to the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

`std::bit_cast` alone is not enough since results will vary by the endian of the system.

Fortunately `<bit>` also contains `std::endian`.

Keeping in mind that optimizers generally compile-time resolve `if`s that are always true or false, we can test endianness and act accordingly.

We only know beforehand how to handle big or little-endian. If it is not one of those, bit_cast results are not decodable.

Another factor that can spoil things is padding. Using bit_cast assumes 0 padding between array elements.

So we can check if there is no padding and the endianness is big or little to see if it is castable.

- If it is not castable, we do a bunch of shifts as per the old method.
  *(this can be slow)*
- If the endianness is `big` -- return the results of bit_cast.
- If the endianness is `little` -- reverse the order. *Not the same as c++23 byteswap, as we swap elements.*

I arbitrarily decided that big-endian has the correct order with the high bits at x[0].

```cpp
#include <bit>
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
#include <climits>
#include <concepts>

template <std::integral F, std::integral T>
    requires (sizeof(F) >= sizeof(T))
constexpr auto split(F x) { 
    enum consts {
        FBITS=sizeof(F)*CHAR_BIT,
        TBITS=sizeof(F)*CHAR_BIT,
        ELEM=sizeof(F)/sizeof(T),
        BASE=FBITS-TBITS,
        MASK=~0ULL >> BASE
    };
    using split=std::array<T, ELEM>;
    const bool is_big=std::endian::native==std::endian::big;
    const bool is_little=std::endian::native==std::endian::little;
    const bool can_cast=((is_big || is_little)
        && (sizeof(F) == sizeof(split)));

    // All the following `if`s should be eliminated at compile time
    // since they are always true or always false
    if (!can_cast)
    {
        split ret;
        for (int e = 0; e < ELEM; ++e)
        {
            ret[e]=(x>>(BASE-e*TBITS)) & MASK;
        }
        return ret;
    }
    split tmp=std::bit_cast<split>(x);
    if (is_big)
    {
        return tmp;
    }
    split ret;
    for (int e=0; e < ELEM; ++e)
    {
        ret[e]=tmp[ELEM-(e+1)];
    }
    return ret;
}

auto tst(uint64_t x, int y)
{
    return split<decltype(x), uint32_t>(x)[y];
}
```

I believe this should be defined behavior.

*EDIT: changed uint64 base to template parameter and minor edit tweaks*

Comment: See it here: https://godbolt.org/z/cjM8W64qz

Comment: @Jarod42 This should handle endianess

Comment: the question is if OP needs endian-aware result, because often tasks like that assume that you have use memory-order, not value-order, i.t for converting data to networked format

Comment: You can use `std::endian` to force to a wire format based on std::native and the goal. In every case I can think of, you need to know the machine endian to decide how to convert.

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother, because arithmetic is faster anyway:

```
uint64_t v;
uint32_t lower = v;
uint32_t upper = v >> 32;
```

Comment: Splitting in two, like converting a 64-bit to two 32-bit, is the same speed using `bit_cast`  with `std::endian` or bit twiddling. Splitting in four, like converting a 64-bit to four 16-bit is faster using bit_cast with `std::endian.`

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum No, arithmetic (this includes bit twiddling) is typically faster than memory operations. Although, in this case, the compiler can probably see through the trivial memory operation and convert it to arithmetic.