# Is bit_cast with endian enough to avoid undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, type-punning

I have this as my answer to another question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/69920195/2963099)

But I am curious if the following is Undefined Behavior:

It would seem that checking endian and assuring 0 padding is sufficient to allow the modern equivalent of cowboy casting.

```cpp
#include <bit>
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
#include <concepts>

template <std::integral T>
auto split64(uint64_t x) { 
    enum consts {
        BITS=sizeof(uint64_t)*8,
        ELEM=sizeof(uint64_t)/sizeof(T),
        BASE=BITS-ELEM,
        MASK=~0ULL >> (BITS-(BITS/ELEM))
    };
    using split=std::array<T, ELEM>;
    static const bool is_big=std::endian::native==std::endian::big;
    static const bool is_little=std::endian::native==std::endian::little;
    static const bool can_cast=((is_big || is_little)
        && (sizeof(uint64_t) == sizeof(split)));

    // All ifs can be eliminated at compile time
    // since they are always true or always false
    if (!can_cast)
    {
        split ret;
        for (int e = 0; e < ret.size(); ++e)
        {
            ret[e]=(x>>(BASE-e*ELEM)) & MASK;
        }
        return ret;
    }
    split tmp=std::bit_cast<split>(x);
    if (is_big)
    {
        return tmp;
    }
    split ret;
    for (int e=0; e < ELEM; ++e)
    {
        ret[e]=tmp[ELEM-(e+1)];
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure a simple `return bit_cast<split>(x);` is not Undefined Behavior in the first place provided that `sizeof(uint64_t)` is a multiple of `sizeof(T)`. The values produced can be implementation-specific though.

Comment: `BITS=sizeof(uint64_t)*CHAR_BIT`

Comment: Silly question: When would zero-padding ever kick in? All `std::integral` types have sizes that are multiples of one-another.

Comment: `0 padding is sufficient` Pedantically, I think you should also add `&& is_trivially_copyable<std::array<T, ELEM>> && alingof(T) >= alignof(uint64_t)`. So, anyway, what happens when `T` is greater than `sizeof(uint64_t)`? `__unit128_t` -> `/ELEM` -> `/0` ;)

Comment: @KamilCuk: Alignment is unnecessary, and trivial copyability is required by `array` if `T` is trivially copyable.

Comment: @KamilCuk the templateT is restricted to std::integral so I believe no __uinit128_t and no issue with trivial copy. I'm replacing uint64_t with another std::integral template parameter (F) and do have the check that sizeof F > sizeof T. But alignment is interesting, I had assumed smaller sizeof would yield same or smaller align, so that should work.

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum: "*__uinit128_t*" If such a type existed, then it would undoubtedly be `integral`. Implementations are permitted to expose more integral types than required by the standard.

Comment: @NicolBolas if only it were that simple. libstdc++ in standard mode has __int128 and it is intentionally not integral. See https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=96710

Comment: The answer I referenced at the top of the OP has been updated with sizeof F > sizeof T and uses CHAR_BIT