# In C or C++, is memory layout of uint64_t guaranteed to be the same as uint32_t[2] ? Can one be cast as the other?

Tags: c++, memory

In C or C++, is memory layout of uint64_t guaranteed to be the same as uint32_t[2] ?  Can I cast one to the other and have them always work as expected?  Does it depend upon if the CPU is 32bit or 64bit or is it compiler implementation dependent?

Comment: In C++, no.  They are unrelated types and cannot be punned.

Comment: Seems like a XY. What do you intend to solve?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type-pun uint64\_t as two uint32\_t in C++20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69911406/type-pun-uint64-t-as-two-uint32-t-in-c20)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In C or C++, is memory layout of uint64_t guaranteed to be the same as uint32_t[2] ?

No. Endianess.

> Can one be cast as the other?

Maybe, maybe not, in C. A pointer to an array of 2 `uint32_t` may not be aligned to `uint64_t`. When the resulting pointer is not properly aligned, it's undefined behavior. [https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p7](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p7)

Yes in C++. https://eel.is/c++draft/expr#reinterpret.cast-7

> Can I cast one to the other and have them always work as expected?

No. Possibly, you can cast, but you can't *access* the data with the handle after casting. It would be a strict alias violation.

> Does it depend upon if the CPU is 32bit or 64bit

Not really.

> or is it compiler implementation dependent?

Because the behavior would be undefined, it's very much compiler dependent.

Answer (score 2):

At least since C++20 there are no special integer values in C++ (as opposed to, I think, C, where they in theory still exist), and hence all bit combinations of two adjacent uint32 objects form a valid 64 bit integer bit sequence.

Casting a pointer is still disallowed because of aliasing and potentially alignment issues, but in C++20 you can  use `std::bit_cast()` to obtain a bit-wise copy of the original: `uint32_t arr[2] = {}; uint64_t ui64 = std::bit_cast<uint64_t>(arr);`. Note that this performs a copy.

As Kamil said, the result may be surprising on a little endian system, but it is valid.

There is an hour-long, medium interesting [CppCon talk about type punning](https://youtu.be/_qzMpk-22cc)  by Timur Doumler on youtube. [52 minutes into the talk](https://youtu.be/_qzMpk-22cc?t=3143) he calls the inability to interpret bytes as different types "the last hole in the object model of C++" and says he'll write a proposal to fix it by introducing an equivalent to `alignas`, e.g. `layoutas(T)` that tells the compiler to accept interpretations as T.